# inserting form data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Please advise how to do this php mysql form and data insert.Already searched on this site and couldn't find any question regarding this.

I have a form that collects student information - student_info(fields: id, name, sex, dob). I can insert this to a table. Now I would like to create two other tables like this 
male_students (id, student_info_id, male_names)
female_students (id, student_info_id, female_names).
My idea for these two separate tables is because I can show the list of male and female easily by a SELECT query.
To do this, I thought I can do this but I am not sure how and if this is even a right approach.

1. for example I have a script called form_submit.php - this has the form
2. filling and submitting the form would insert data into student_info tables.
3. when doing the step 2, I would like to check if ($sex == male) or (if $sec==female), do a insert into male_students and female_students respectively.

but I am stuck

1. should i just write three individual queries inside the
   form_submit.php ?
2. how to get the student_info_id for these two
       tables. I thought of LAST_INSERT_ID but I am confused what will
       happen if two users fill out the form at same time. So how to
       approach this?

If this is not even a right way to approach, how to populate the data for those two tables?

Please advise.

regards

Comment: Why do you need to split the data up? You've already got a field to denote the sex of each student, so you can just add that into your query when you're searching.

Comment: `Already searched on this site and couldn't find any question regarding this` I don't believe this

Comment: why would you want to split in female and male, i can´t think of a way to add more redundancy. the way to select the males is to `select from student_info where sex='male'`

Comment: just add a `WHERE sex='male'`when you want one or another, don't add 3 tables when 1 is more than enough

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Anecdote: At a government job years ago we had a project to add "several new options" to the "Gender" enumeration in the data. I'm all for covering our bases, but *"several"*? I suggested that instead of changing the possible answers we simply change the question to: "When faced with male/female public restrooms, which do you choose?" But they didn't like that idea.

Comment: You make tables based on what you want to get out of it. Usually when working with names, you want to split the first name and the surname. Sex would be an extra field. It would not be any harder to retrieve all male students or all female students (SELECT * from students WHERE sex=0), but it would be more convenient if you want to do queries where you would want to retrieve both male and female students.

Comment: @STTLCU , then send me the link and i will look at it. I am not here to start a discussion with your findings. thanks.

Comment: @andrewsi - I certainly agree with you. I just thought of doing it for load purpose and thought if i query a separate table then it wil be easy.I can do with that one query itself.

Comment: MySql indexes are blazingly fast if you use them. Don't try to optimize this prematurely. There are real performance problems and there are incorrectly conceived performance problems. This one is the latter.

Comment: @JoeFrambach - `Sex is not binary.` - Yeah, I heard it is complicated ;-)

Comment: @JoeFrambach, any suggested link to know about indexing as I am stil new.I can google but if there is anything you can suggest for basic understanding.

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to split "males" and "females" into their own tables in this scenario.  (And I'm at a loss to imagine any scenario where it would make sense.)

The entity you're storing is, for lack of a better term, a Person.  (User, Individual, etc. could be used in this context as well.  Stick with whatever language is appropriate for the domain.)  So a Person is a record in a table.  Gender is an attribute of a Person, so it's a data element on that table.  A highly simplified structure to convey this might be:

```
Person
----------
ID (integer)
GivenName (string)
FamilyName (string)
Gender (enumeration)
```

The `Gender` value would simply be a selected value from whichever possible options are available.  Such options might include:

- Male
- Female
- Unknown
- Undisclosed

There are medical cases where there may be even more options, and psychological cases may indeed further add to the set.  But for most domains that might be covered by "Unknown" or "Undisclosed" (or perhaps "Other" as an option, though that might look strange on the form to the vast majority of users).

To select this information, you'd simply add a `WHERE` clause to your query.  Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Gender=1
```

If `1` maps to, for example, `Male` then this would select all `Person`s who have a `Gender` attribute of `Male`.